# Wordpress - Multiple Post Thumbnails not saving on update

Tags: wordpress

I have been using this plugin for sometime now ... all has been working fine up until about a week ago.

I have 5 extra thumbnail fields, 3 of them work, but the other 2 wont save when i hit the update button ... I click 'set new thumbnail' then choose the image, it then goes into the admin screen just fine ... as soon as i hit update though, it dissapears.

The other thing is that it only happens in certain categories.

I have uninstalled & updated the plugin ... still nothing.

I have no idea what else to try.  Any help would be great

Comment: What's the name of the plugin? Have you tried de-activating all other plugins but this one? Which theme are you using? Which version of WordPress are you using?

Comment: Did u ever solve this? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the Custom Fields seemed to fix it for me.